# Javascript Best way to handle arrays that could be one element in length

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I realize might be subjective... but I was running into issues when looping over an "array".

When the "array" is more than one element... it is actually an array, and so my `for...of` and `array.forEach` work fine.

But if the function receives only one item, then it is not an array, it is simply an object and I run into issues.

I solved this issue by wrapping it in an if statement, but that seems kinda crazy to do every time I am looping over something that could actually be a single object rather than an array of objects.

```js
async function writeToDB(myArray: []) {
  const db = await openDB("DomainsDB", 1);
  const tx = db.transaction("Domains", "readwrite");

  if (myArray.length > 1) {
    myArray.forEach(async(r: any) => {
      await tx.store.add(r["SearchHeader"]);
    });
  } else {
    await tx.store.add(myArray["SearchHeader"]);
  }
  await tx.done;
}
```

Comment: If you're using typescript, how are you allowed to call the function with anything other than an array?

Comment: noImplicitAny is set to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `myArray` type is an array, TypeScript should block you from assigning single items. This can happen if you use Javascript without types support, or if you use the babble plugin that removes the typing on build (in that case the IDE should warn you about this).

---

**Possible solutions to this issue in JS:**

You can concat `myArray` to an empty array. If `myArray` is an array or a single item, the result will always be an array:

```
async function writeToDB(myArray: []) {
  const db = await openDB("DomainsDB", 1);
  const tx = db.transaction("Domains", "readwrite");

  const arr = [].concat(myArray); // the result is always an array
  arr.forEach(async(r: any) => {
    await tx.store.add(r["SearchHeader"]);
  });

  await tx.done;
}
```

Another option is to assign `myArray` to another array, and use `Array.flat()`:

```
async function writeToDB(myArray: []) {
  const db = await openDB("DomainsDB", 1);
  const tx = db.transaction("Domains", "readwrite");

  const arr = [myArray].flat(); // the result is always an array
  arr.forEach(async(r: any) => {
    await tx.store.add(r["SearchHeader"]);
  });

  await tx.done;
}
```

Comment: OP is using TypeScript. If OP is able to call it without an array than there's something really _fishy_

Comment: Yep. I agree with you and Adiga :)